# How to get a variable inside view helper $this->view?

Tags: zend-framework, variables, controller, view-helpers

I need to run in my zend project, inside a controller something like:
`<?php for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
    $this->view->someVariable.$i = $someClassName->someFunction();
        } ?>`
But it doesn't work. I tried to declare `$this->view->someVariable`, but it doesn't work any way . Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need curly braces:

```
$this->view->{$this->view->someVariable . $i} = $someClassName->function();
```

although I can't help but wonder what you're trying to achieve. Have you dumped the return value of `$someClassName->function()?`

Comment: I'm kind of surprised PHP lets you get away with that and doesn't throw a fatal.

Comment: Actiually You helped. I just use $this->view->{someVariable.$i} = $someClassName->someFunction(); and it works! Why I need this - that way I can extract headers of 3 latest articles from MySql table, assign them to variables and render them on homepage of the site. thank You!

Answer (score 2):

`$this->view->someVariable.$i` is an expression not a variable so you cant assign a value to it. If `$this->view->someVariable` is an array you can assign values to its elements like,

```
<?php 
for ($i=1; $i<10; $i++){ 
    $this->view->someVariable[$i] = $someClassName->someFunction(); 
} 
?>
```